# How to capture mouse clicks outside of form (like with Code Insight in Delphi)

Tags: delphi

I like the idea of the Delphi Code Insight window (custom listbox on form without borders basically) where you can click outside of the form and it will close it automatically.

My first thought was to call SetCapture/ReleaseCapture in the FormCreate and FormDestroy respectively. I set the form's caption to X/Y on the FormMouseMove, but it doesn't update the coordinates outside of the form.

If I call SetCapture/ReleaseCapture from within MouseDown and MouseUp, it does update the coordinates as expected, so that proves the concept does work.

I tried other things as well, e.g. post a WM_USER in the OnShow event, and call SetCapture from there, but it still doesn't update the coordinates. I then tried the TApplicationEvents component (OnMessage), but that doesn't work either.

I've read several articles already, but wasn't able to find what I was looking for. Some articles called SetCapture from within the MouseMove, but that doesn't work when the mouse cursor starts outside of the form. Hrm...

The next step would be to use a WindowsHook, but that's where I stopped. I know how to implement one, but it just seems like I'm missing something really obvious here. There must be a simpler way to do this.

Any ideas? :)

Cheers,
Jarno

Comment: Hi, sorry still pretty new here. ;) I actually discovered that this only partially solves the problem. When I click on another app, the WM_KILLFOCUS stops the modal form, but this doesn't work when I click on the main form of the same application. So I'm back to the above problem again.

Comment: Try to consider the mouse hooks as you mentioned. If you imagine, that you'll get all mouse messages wherever they happen. In the message handler is enough to filter "clicks" (mouse downs) and check if the cursor is over my form. If not, close the form. If yes, dispatch it. Sure you have to do something with your component(s) what can even invoke form close, because of infinite popup loop (as ShowModal do).

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done easier by adding TApplicationEvents to your form and use the event [OnDeactivate](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/AppEvnts_TApplicationEvents_OnDeactivate.html). That one gets triggered whenever the application loses focus.

Comment: I tried that as well now, but same problem as with WM_KILLFOCUS - it only works when you click on another application, but not within the same application. I have started wondering whether I should be using a modeless form instead, but then I would have to wait for the form to finish with Application.ProcessMessages. That's kind of an unknown to me, because I don't how this will affect the rest of my application. The concept itself works, because I can now trap WM_KILLFOCUS, but I do still prefer the idea of ShowModal at this stage however.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can help you somehow. As they say, if the mouse is captured, this message is sent to the window that has captured the mouse. So I would capture the mouse for the form and then wait until result of this message is HTNOWHERE, which should mean "out of the window".
But as far as I can remember, this never worked for me fine, so I finally used (as you mentioned) mouse hook.
But in my case I've had a lot of components on that popup form and you need to consider messaging for them too.
The implementation I've used (with a little changes) and which works [is here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_10047215.html).

Comment: Cool. I don't have access to experts-exchange, but I'll ask around at work tomorrow. I just finished a new test version. I'm using AppEvents.OnDeactivate to check whether a mouse click occurred outside the application, and I'm currently using a mouse hook to 'detect' mouse clicks outside the form. It appears to work, but I have much more testing to do. I looked at DBLookup before, but ran into the same problem as you, e.g. needs to handle more than one component. The only thing I could still do is check out the Lazarus IDE code. I couldn't really find the unit, but will keep looking. ;)

Comment: Try this cheat :) Open google, find some experts exchange answer and open it through click. Then copy the experts exchange URL address, open google again and paste this address to the searching box. Then you'll find the only one link. And now when you open this only link, you'll get the free answer. This works fine for me about 2 years :P And with it, you'll get also some cookie, which then thinks you're registered, so you don't need to repeat this "workaround" ...

Comment: Hrm, didn't quite work for me. But I was able to view the Cached version in full. ;) Looks like they are using GetDesktopWindow as the parent. Haven't tried that yet. Apparently Borland uses a TPopupListBox control (WinSpy?). I tried googling that and came up with a few places that merely use the TListBox as a popup (not like the form that I'm using). Sounds promising, and certainly simpler than my MouseHook approach. ;)

Comment: When I tried to implement combo by myself I gave up at default message handling, which you have to redial at popup. Anyway TPopupListBox you can find in unit Grids.pas

Comment: >> which you have to redirect at popup << sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (I needed to implement a scrolling windows if the mouse pointer hovered over a special area and I was not able to use SetCapture)
and circumvented it using a timer + GetCursorPos method.
Just do then a ScreenToClient and check if the mouse is within the window.